# Changing background color for selected list <li>...</li>

Tags: jquery

Once we click on any `<li>` in the accordion, it should be selected (applying some background color) until we will click another `<li>`. I tried following code, can anyone help me?

```
 $("#accordian h3").click(function() {
      var txt = $(this).text();
      //alert(txt);
      //slide up all the link lists
      $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
      //$(this).css('border-left','18px solid #ff1800');
      //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
      if(!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
           $(this).next().slideDown();
      }
     })
 });

 /*  $("li").click(function(){
      $(this).css('background','orange');
 }); */
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5Hd4/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('orange').siblings('li').removeClass('orange');
});
```

[**Update Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J5Hd4/6/)

Comment: do you want the change the color of the heading(dashbard, task, etc..) ? I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot....first solution is correct and I want header's forseparate color....

Answer (score 1):

**[Working solution!](http://jsfiddle.net/J5Hd4/3/)**

**jQuery:**

```
$("#accordian ul li ul li").click(function(){
        $('#accordian ul li ul li').removeClass('red');
        $(this).addClass('red');
     });
```

**CSS:**

```
.red, .red:hover, .red:active {
    background: #f00 !important;
}
```

*And CSS Modification:*

```
/*hover effect on links*/
#accordian ul ul li:hover {
    background: #003545;
    border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/J5Hd4/1/

```
$("#accordian h3").click(function(){
        var txt = $(this).text();   
    $('#accordian h3').css('background', '#003040'); // this gives the default background you have to all the h3's
        //slide up all the link lists
        $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
    $(this).css('background','orange');  // this gives the new background only to the one that was clicked on
        if(!$(this).next().is(":visible"))
        {
            $(this).next().slideDown();
        }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks...but it should be applicable siblings as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("#accordian h3").click(function () {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
        $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
    $('#accordian li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5Hd4/5/)**